# C++ CUDA Gridsize meaning clarification

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia, gpgpu, semantics

I am new to CUDA programming. I am currently in the process of doing Monte Carlo Simulations on a high number of large data samples.

Im trying to dynamically maximize and calculate the number of Blocks to submit to the GPU. The issue i have is that i am unclear on how to calculate the maximum number of blocks i can submit to my GPU at one time.

Here is the output of my GPU when querying it:

```
-----------------------------------------------
CUDA Device #:                   0
Name:                            NVIDIA GeForce GTX 670
Revision number:                 3.0
Warp size:                       32
Maximum threads per block:       1024
Maximum Grid size:               2147483647
Multiprocessor Count:            7
-----------------------------------------------
```

What i am unclear on is that the maximum number of thread per block is clearly defined as 1024 but the grid size is not (at least to me). when i looked around in the documentation and online the definition is as follow:

```
int cudaDeviceProp::maxGridSize[3] [inherited]
Maximum size of each dimension of a grid
```

What i wanna know is the grid size reffering to:

- The maximum total number of threads that can be submitted to the GPU?
  (therefore i would calculate the number of blocks like so: `MAX_GRID_SIZE / MAX_THREAD_PER_BLOCK`)
- The Maximum number of blocks of 1024 threads (therefore i would simply use `MAX_GRID_SIZE`)

The last one seems kind of insane to me since the MAX_GRID_SIZE = 2^31-1 (2147483647) therefore the maximum number of threads would be (2^31-1)*1024 = ~ 2.3 Trillions threads. Which is why i tend to think the first option is correct. But i am looking for outside input.

I have found many discussion about the subject of calculating blocks but almost all of them were specific to one GPU and not the general way of calculating it or thinking about it.

Comment: The second definition is correct. If you have a very short kernel, I would think using the maximum would take less than a day (at least in that ballpark). The blocks of a grid can run one after the other (the threads of different blocks run possibly not at the same time), so it is more or less a loop around everything. You can do similar things yourself, by calling your kernel within loops several times, or put loops within the threads of your kernel; or (advanced) you can start new kernels from within your running kernels.

Comment: If you want to know, how many threads can run at one time, the answer is much less. There is a maximum number of threads per SM=multiprocessor (depending on model around 1024 to 2048). Each multiprocessor has 4 partitions, which can independently schedule instructions (so for 4 warps per SM max.), but the instructions need more cycles to be finished, so several are in flight. If all the threads of a warp want to do independent instructions instead of independent data, then they cannot be scheduled at the same time, and the scheduler can in the worst case only schedule 1 thread.

Comment: So 4 new instructions per SM per cycle is the worst case (and this only if the resources for the instruction are available). Typically those instructions are executed by warps running in lockstep, so 128 threads would receive a new instruction.

Comment: @Sebastian Does that mean that the way i calculate the maximum number of threads i can pushed to my GPU would be nb_of_multiprocessor * max_grid_size * max_thread_per_block ?

Comment: No, the numbere of threads you can push with one kernel call would still be `max_grid_size * max_thread_per_block`. The `number of multiprocessors * number of threads per multiprocessor` would give you the number of threads running at the same time and this number is much lower than the former. (There are some more possibly limiting restrictions, if your kernel uses a lot of resources).

Comment: This number of pushable threads per kernel call is not very relevant. You can just call your kernels several times or use streams to call several kernels at the same time instead. The number of threads in a block are much more relevant, as those threads can better cooperate (e.g. shared memory or synchronization over barriers), and are guaranteed to run at the same time (on the same multiprocessor).

Comment: Well each thread has to run computation on data that is reliant on each other so i do it in a loop in the kernel, but the number of indepenpendant simulation i have to run is around 300 000. but the total number of calculation is about 1.8 Trillion. So from what you tell me i could probably submit the whole thing in one go.

Comment: So you can just put other outer loops for independent simulations in your kernel or better put another loop on CPU=host side around your kernel call. In this way you can save and resume the results of some independent simulations or update a progress bar.

Comment: Check, if you can somehow formulate your simulation (even possibly some independent ones combined) as small matrix multiplications, then you can perhaps use the Tensor cores (which are even faster). Otherwise current GPUs can achieve ~10 Teraflops, which is under theoretical best cases 10 trillion floating point operations per second. So nothing unrealistic about your plans. In the end shuffling the data around could be the limiting factor. Or hopefully your simulations can run with the same instruction, but different data, instead of lots of conditional branches.

Comment: Well at the moment each simulation has 3 parameters that change (which can be tought as sim config) and i submit a kernel and get the results for the config on each call, but my GPU utilisation is not maximized, at the moment it takes about 20-30 min to complete. So i was looking to make batches with multiple configuration to maximize GPU utilisation and speed up the whole simulation.

Comment: If you have 300 000 threads and e.g. 1024 threads per block, then you get ~300 blocks, a typical number for a kernel call. It is enough to distribute nicely to SMs. (If you have the expensive A100, then you have 128 SMs, then you should think about using more blocks or around a multiple of 128 to not waste SMs with having nothing to do). A RTX 3090Ti has 84 SMs. So each SM would process 3 to 4 blocks.

Comment: Making batches sounds like a good idea. You can use Nvidia Compute Nsight to benchmark and understand the limits of your kernels better. To come back to your initial question, it does not help with utilization to have batches with more threads than can run at the same time.

Comment: Well each kernel call has 1024 threads which is my current number of samples which all have 6000 data points. so i have 300 000 different sim configuration to go through. Anyway, beyond that you have more than answered my first question. Feel free to post an answer and ill accept it thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Nvidia CUDA the grid size signifies the number of blocks (not the number of threads), which are sent to the GPU in one kernel invocation.

The maximum grid size can be and is huge, as the CUDA programming model does not (normally) give any guarantee that blocks run at the same time. This helps to run the same kernels on low-end and high-end hardware of different generations. So the grid is for independent tasks, the threads in a block can cooperate (especially with shared memory and synchronization barriers).

So a very large grid is more or less the same as an automatic loop around your kernel invocation or within your kernel around your code.

If you want to optimize the occupancy (parallel efficiency) of your GPU to the maximum, you should calculate, how many threads can run at the same time.

The typical maximum is `maximum number of threads per SM` x `number of SMs`. The GTX 670 has 7 SMs (called SMX for that generation) with a maximum of 1024 threads each. So for maximum occupancy you can run a multiple of 7x1024 threads.

There are other limiting factors for the 1024 threads per multiprocessor, mainly the amount of registers and shared memory each of your threads or blocks need. The GTX has 48 KB shared memory per SM and 65536 32-bit registers per SM. So if you limit your threads to 64 registers per thread, then you can use the 1024 threads per block.

Sometimes, one runs kernels with less than the maximum size, e.g. 256 threads per block. The GTX 670 can run up to a maximum of 16 blocks per SM at the same time. But you cannot get more threads than 1024 per SM altogether. So nothing gained.

To optimize your kernel itself or get nice graphical and numeric feedback, about the efficiency and bottlenecks of your kernel, use the Nvidia Compute Nsight tool (if there is a version, which still supports the 3.0 Kepler generation).

To get full speed, it is typically important to optimize memory accesses (coalescing) and to make sure that the 32 threads within a warp are running in perfect lockstep. Additionally you should try to replace accesses to global memory with accesses to shared memory (be careful about bank conflicts).